# Binary search implementation not working with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm learning algorithm and so that I'm trying to convert a python implementation of binary search into Javascript but this isn't working. I couldn't figure this out.

```js
var search = function(array, key) {
  let begin = 0;
  let end = array.length - 1;
  while (begin <= end) {
    var mid = (begin + end) / 2;
    if (key == array[mid]) {
      return mid;
      break;
    } else if (key > array[mid]) {
      begin = mid + 1;
    } else if (key < array[mid]) {
      end = mid - 1;
    }
    return null
  }
}
var arr = [9, 56, 89, 333, 143, 543, 64, 332, 23];
var info = arr.sort((arr, b) => {
  return arr - b
});
console.log(search(info, 9));

//Output is always null
```

Comment: can you define "_this isn't working_". Does it crash, have an unexpected result, do nothing at all?

Comment: You are going to end up returning mid or null within the first iteration ending the whole search function, your search never goes through the whole array

Comment: `return null` should be after while loop. Also `arr, b` is a lot confusing for the sort, use `a, b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a subtle bug in your program.

Firstly, `return null` should be outside `while` and now for the main part `(begin + end) / 2` , if `(begin + end)` is odd , dividing by 2 returns a float not an int for the index.

so you have to use `parseInt()` like `var mid = parseInt((begin + end) / 2);`

http://jsbin.com/vewuculavo/1/edit?js,console

Comment: WOW, Thanks this one is a real answer, Not just a cookie cutter.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected a little:

```js
var search = function(array, key) {
  let begin = 0;
  let end = array.length - 1;
  while (begin <= end) {
    var mid = Math.floor((begin + end) / 2);
    if (key == array[mid]) {
      return array[mid];
    } else if (key > array[mid]) {
      begin = mid + 1;
    } else if (key < array[mid]) {
      end = mid - 1;
    }
  }
  return null
}
var arr = [9, 56, 89, 333, 143, 543, 64, 332, 23];
var info = arr.sort((arr, b) => {
  return arr - b
});
console.log(info);
console.log(search(info, 9));
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the return null that seems to be misplaced, I see another problem:

If your array has a length that is even, (i.e: 8)

```
begin = 0, end = 8 - 1 = 7, => mid = (begin + end) / 2 = 7 / 2 = 3.5
```

And JavaScript will return:

```
array[mid] = array[3.5] = undefined
```

Comment: YES True, So How can I deal with this?

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that you have your return null inside you while loop. Move it outside the loop

```
var search = function(array, key) {
 let begin = 0;
 let end = array.length - 1;
 while (begin <= end) {
   var mid = Math.floor((begin + end) / 2);
   if (key == array[mid]) {
     return mid;
   } else if (key > array[mid]) {
     begin = mid + 1;
   } else if (key < array[mid]) {
     end = mid - 1;
   }
 }
 return null;   
}
```

Comment: No, it is not working. Still, the same output: null and it's say's infinite loop detected.

Comment: The issue is with non Integer division in JS which is causing the infinite loop
var mid = Math.floor((begin + end) / 2);

Comment: Yes, Thanks now it is working. However, I've seen guy's are using Math.floor to get this done But I couldn't understand that one.

Comment: @CodeCooker, `Math.floor(2.3)=2`, `Math.ceil(2.3)=3`. That's all.

Comment: Got it. However, we can use `parseInt()` to get this done easily. as the most recent answer.

Comment: @CodeCooker or -> `(begin + end) / 2 | 0` this avoids floating point all together, and could give a bit of a performance boost.